# Magento Extension to Filter Category Products By Vehicle Year / Make / Model

Tags: magento, filtering

I've seen quite a lot of extensions that do Year/Make/Model **search** of products, that's not what i am after.

What i want is to let a customer select his vehicle YMM (year make model) and once he did, i want all the products shown to only fit that vehicle in any category he navigates to. So say we have 2 categories - suspension and brakes; once the vehicle type is chosen, only parts fitting that vehicle will be shown under suspension and under brakes.

I also want to be able to define universal products which will be shown regardless of vehicle type chosen.

So far couldn't find such an extension.

Any help or pointers will be greatly appreciated.

I am open to implementing something myself if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this extension : http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/parts-finder.html 
I have gone through this module and with little modification,it serves both your purpose.

1) It has filters for individual categories as well. Lets say if you want that once filtered, the same products should be shown in all the categories, you can customize that little part on your own.

2) It has global import section,which will display the products regardless of the filters chosen.

Comment: One more extensions for [magento 2 year make model](https://www.mageants.com/product-parts-finder-extension-for-magento-2.html) of MageAnts vendor it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this Year Make Model magento extension in many sites - http://mage-extensions-themes.com/magento-extensions/top-magento-extensions-for-auto-parts-store/year-make-model-professional.html
It seems to have high popularity in Magento Connect. You may want to try that.